# Can't use yandex-geocoder with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python 2.7. I install library pip install yandex-geocoder, but error:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement yandex-geocoder (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for yandex-geocoder
```

Answer (score 0):

Yandex geocoder does not support python 2.7 version. As you can see [here](https://pypi.org/project/yandex-geocoder/), this library support only python 3.6 or python 3.7

Comment: yes, I know version 3.6, but I install 3.6, but I have error:
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

To use [yandex-geocoder](https://pypi.org/project/yandex-geocoder/), your python version must be >=3.6.

Go to [Python downloads](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/), download and install python 3.6. Then you will be able to use [yandex-geocoder](https://pypi.org/project/yandex-geocoder/).

Comment: @user357670 [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)